# Rails 3.1 active record query to an array of arrays for CSV export via FastCSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, csv

I'm attempting to DRY up a method I've been using for a few months:

```
def export(imagery_requests)
  csv_string = FasterCSV.generate do |csv|    
    imagery_requests.each do |ir|
      csv << [ir.id, ir.service_name, ir.description, ir.first_name, ir.last_name, ir.email,
        ir.phone_contact, ir.region, ir.imagery_type, ir.file_type, ir.pixel_type,
        ir.total_images, ir.tile_size, ir.progress, ir.expected_date, ir.high_priority,
        ir.priority_justification, ir.raw_data_location, ir.service_overviews,
        ir.is_def, ir.isc_def, ir.special_instructions, ir.navigational_path,
        ir.fyqueue, ir.created_at, ir.updated_at]
    end
  end
  # send it to the browser with proper headers
  send_data csv_string,
    :type => 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present',
    :disposition => "attachment; filename=requests_as_of-#{Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d")}.csv"
end
```

I figured it would be a LOT better if instead of specifying EVERY column manually, I did something like this:

```
def export(imagery_requests)
  csv_string = FasterCSV.generate do |csv|
    line = []
    imagery_requests.each do |ir|
      csv << ir.attributes.values.each do |i|
        line << i
      end      
    end
  end
  # send it to the browser with proper headers
  send_data csv_string,
    :type => 'text/csv; charset=iso-8859-1; header=present',
    :disposition => "attachment; filename=requests_as_of-#{Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d")}.csv"
end
```

That should be creating an array of arrays. It works just fine in the Rails console. But in the production environment, it just produces garbage output. I'd much rather make this method extensible so I can add more fields to the ImageryRequest model at a later time. Am I going about this all wrong?

Comment: What you say "garbage output" can you give an example?

Comment: 乜瑡潩慮屬浉条牥屹敁楲污偟潨潴牧灡票㉜㄰弱佄兑䥜慤潨㉟㄰弱䅎偉摟煯獱 sorry for the delay... holidays....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that it probably works in the console when you do it for just one `imagery_request`, yes?
But when you do multiple it fails?

Again I'm guessing that's because you never reset `line` to be an empty array again. So you're continually filling a single array.

Try the simple way first, to check it works, then start going all `<<` on it then:

```
csv_string = FasterCSV.generate do |csv|
  imagery_requests.each do |ir|
    csv << ir.attributes.values.clone
  end
end
```

PS - in the past I've even used `clone` on my line-by-line array, just to be sure I wasn't doing anything untoward with persisted stuff...

Comment: I wasn't doing the CSV generate step in the console... just generating the same array that I'd use to feed to FasterCSV. I'll give this a shot though.

Comment: ok - you probably need to start adding puts lines so you can see/check what the actual values are from `attributes.values`

Comment: Also - I thought of a simplification. have a look :)

Comment: Looks like even my ORIGINAL implementation is now yielding the garbage characters too! All bets are off then. I bet either one of your implementations will work just fine once I find out what else got messed up.

Comment: Somehow, Libre-Office Calc switched to Plain Unicode instead of UTF-8. Nice elegant solution!!!